# const_cast setting a rule and breaking it for function const

Tags: c++, c++11, const-cast

In the following example I found on the net, it is mentioned that one of the advantages of `const_cast` is that it allow a constant function changes the class members. It is a question to me. Why should we set a rule for a function by `const` and then breaking that rule with `const_cast`? Isn't it like a cheating? Wouldnt it better to not set `const` for the function at all?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
private:
    int roll;
public:

    student(int r):roll(r) {}

    // A const function that changes roll with the help of const_cast
    void fun() const
    {
        ( const_cast <student*> (this) )->roll = 5;
    }

    int getRoll()  { return roll; }
};

int main(void)
{
    student s(3);
    cout << "Old roll number: " << s.getRoll() << endl;

    s.fun();

    cout << "New roll number: " << s.getRoll() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[reference](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/casting-operators-in-c-set-1-const_cast/)

Comment: funny that getter is not `const`.

Comment: C++ provides many ways to shoot yourself in the foot, this is one of them.

Comment: I thought one of the main justifications for const_cast was to be able to call older C API functions that did not correctly declare their parameters as const (frequently, pointer to const).  This would make these API uncallable from const methods (operating on const members).  But you may know that the function doesn't change its parameters (say, strcmp).  const_cast would let you strip off the const in order to be able to use that function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is indeed a bad idea. As well as lying about the function's behaviour, it allows you to modify a member of a constant `student` object, giving undefined behaviour.

In general, a member function should be `const` if, and only if, it doesn't modify the object's observable state. So in this case, it should not be `const`.

Sometimes, you might want specific members to be modifiable in a function that doesn't otherwise cause an observable change; for example, locking a mutex to access shared data, or caching the result of a complex calculation. In that case, declare those members `mutable`, so that the rest of the class is still protected by `const`-correctness.

Answer (score 2):

This is a poor example of `const_cast` usage. Imagine a better example. A method of a published class was not declared as `const` by mistake. You have a const-reference to this class and want to call this method. But you cannot do it, because it was not declared as `const` *by mistake*. In this case, you can say to the compiler: "Ok, I know what I'm doing, I know this method does not actually change anything, just remove const-ness from that reference and allow me to call this method. Trust me, I'm a programmer".

Real-life example. In OpenCV library, there is no such thing as immutable image. The core class `cv::Mat` is mutable. Suppose you want to create a read-only wrapper around a constant buffer of memory. The only way you can construct it is by casting const away, like this:

```
const char* myConstBuffer = GetConstBuffer();
const cv::Mat myConstImage(const_cast<char*>(myConstBuffer), /* dimensions, etc. */);
```

This is a legal code, since constructed image has type `const cv::Mat` and you cannot call any modifying methods on it. But using `const_cast` here still reveals a design error: there should be a valid way to construct such read-only buffers.

Answer (score 0):

`const` is mostly about expressing intention to callers. When a member function is marked `const`, you're telling *callers* that they can expect the *public interface* of this object not to change.

But imagine a scenario where you want to log calls to this function, with a serial number. That serial number will need to change, but this change is only visible inside the private depths of the class. It's appropriate in this case to "cheat" const my marking the serial number variable as `mutable`.

`const_cast` is similar rationale.

Comment: I don't think `const_cast` is appropriate in this case. Sounds like the perfect case for `mutable`.

Answer (score 0):

The bright example - reference-counting object. In fact reference counting declares object life-time policy, but doesn't relates to real "business" flow of class implementation. While `const` relates to business flow. For example - you have business account, but have no ability to change it:

```
class BusinessAccount{
   unsigned _refcount;
   double _amount
   ...
```

You have some operation to "view"

```
void view(SmartPtr<BusinessAccount> smart_ptr)
```

So if `view` have to take ownership on object - it must increase _refcount.

**PS** the better solution there keyword - `mutable` on field _refcount instead of `const_cast`